# Turn off mobile data in app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm wondering if you can turn off and on mobile data in your app. So for example in the settings menu that there is a switch where you can turn off mobile data only for your app. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe it is allowed as you would have to use a private API to access them settings and private APIs are definitely not allowed by apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way it is possible, but it depends what you want to do.

You can not turn "Mobile Phone's Mobile Data option" off. That is not allowed.

However, you can ALLOW your own APP to use Mobile Data or DISALLOW. That can be a switch in your APP PREFERENCES. I made a similar APP using Video play from internet without real streaming. In that case Apple does not allow you (nor your mobile provider) that you use Mobile Data. So before I start Play the m4a Video, I looked the Network and if it is Mobile Data, I warn the user to switch to WLAN otherwise it will not play the Video.

In this Manner, you can limit. To learn how to do that, you can check Apple "Reachability" Sample APP.

Comment: I already use Reachability to check if wifi or 3G is availble

Comment: Than you can slightly modify your app to see if the data comes over WiFi and according to that you can make decisions

Answer (score 0):

No, i beleave not because allowing these functionalities in the app would mean no use for these setting at all.

Answer (score -1):

You could very well show an alert and redirect them to the settings page.
URL schemes are used to redirect to settings page.
Sample for redirecting to wifi controls in settings page.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];

here is a [link to a tutorial for redirecting to settings page](http://paulpeelen.com/2011/11/30/ios-4-ios-5-tutorial-uialertview-with-link-to-wifi-or-settings-app-using-reachability-and-xcode-4-2/).

Other than this i'am not aware of any other methods.

Comment: obsolete as of iOS 5.1